# Is there a way to return 0 for months with no data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Chart.js to show the total number of transactions (count) for each month.

```
$dataTotal = ModelName::select(DB::raw('count(id) as count'), DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)  as month")) 
                        ->where('org_id', auth()->user()->org_id)
                        ->where('result_code', 200)
                        ->groupBy('month')
                        ->orderBy('month')
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();
```

The query itself is fine, except for the problem that if there is no records in a month then it doesn't return `0` for that month. Which results in the graph not rendering properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions, on how i can implement it so that i receive full resultsets?

The desired format is:

```
array (
0 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 1,
),
1 => 
array (
  'count' => 5,
  'month' => 2,
),
2 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 3,
),
3 => 
array (
  'count' => 4,
  'month' => 4,
),
4 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 5,
),
5 => 
array (
  'count' => 4,
  'month' => 6,
),
6 => 
array (
  'count' => 51225,
  'month' => 7,
),
7 => 
array (
  'count' => 4,
  'month' => 8,
),
8 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 9,
),
9 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 10,
),
10 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 11,
),
11 => 
array (
  'count' => 0,
  'month' => 12,
),

)
```

Comment: You could generate the desired default array and merge with the results. So first generate array like this `$monthlyArray = array(); $emptyMonth = array("count" => 0, "month" => 0); for($i = 1; $i <= 12;$i++){$emptyMonth['month'] = $i;$monthlyArray[$i-1] = $emptyMonth; }`

Comment: `"doesn't return 0"`, what does it return? Please share the current output as well.

Comment: @Digvijay for the records with no data, nothing is returned. So I get an array of only ones with data. Eg `array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'sum' => '19.20',
    'month' => 5,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'count' => 2350,
    'month' => 6,
  ),
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$monthlyArray = array();
$emptyMonth = array('count' => 0, 'month' => 0);
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){//generate an array with default values
    $emptyMonth['month'] = $i;
    $monthlyArray[$i-1] = $emptyMonth;

}

$dataTotal = ModelName::select(DB::raw('count(id) as count'), DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)  as month")) 
                        ->where('org_id', auth()->user()->org_id)
                        ->where('result_code', 200)
                        ->groupBy('month')
                        ->orderBy('month')// you don't really need this one 
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();//fetch the results

foreach($dataTotal as $key => $array){//add the results to the default array
    $monthlyArray[$array['month']-1] = $array;
}
//monthlyArray contains the data
```